# How safe is the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: support, android-app, security

After learning some time ago that the Stack Exchange app was no longer being serviced, I got to wondering how safe is the app?
I tried finding an answer but could not seem to find one. Is someone interested in enlightening me and other who might have this question somewhere in their minds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not safe to use it while driving.

Wait, that's not what you meant, I guess ... Well, there's no reason to assume it's less secure than using your device's browser to access Stack Exchange. In fact, it could be *more* secure, since some critical features (changing your password, deleting your account) are not available in the app. It uses HTTPS for all connections, but no advanced tricks like SSL pinning (but neither does the website).

The app uses push notifications for new items in your global inbox; using the default settings, they'll probably be visible or accessible on your lock screen. If you're worried about leaking information that way, I guess it's best to turn those off or have them delivered silently.

Comment: While true, worth mentioning that since the app is no longer maintained, any new security breach is a big risk since nobody will put a patch/fix for it.

Comment: True. I suppose that if such a breach is discovered, Stack Exchange will send an email to all users, probably invalidating the access tokens and delisting the app (if that didn't happen already). The app doesn't store your password (AFAIK).